# Website is very slow, but if I modify the URL it loads normally

Tags: php, linux, performance, url, web

Not all the time, but sometimes if I visit the site as this http://WEBSITESAMPLE.com/paramA/pathB/, it becomes very slow and nothing loads till a minute or so, but if I add something dummy on the path, it loads immediately, do any of you have an idea why is it?

Comment: This is rather scant in detail (can you add some).  Guess: it could be that your caching recall layer is slow, but requests that bypass the cache are responsive.

Comment: are you using a Framework or something? maybe there's a process in the server side that makes the client wait to load its content. 

What are you using in your source Code, PHP and JS or what? are you using Apache Server?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it is in PHP and I am using the BEAR Sunday framework (https://bearsunday.github.io/), it is in Apache server and it is in production setting and should be caching.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't happen all the time, it rarely happens, but very slow when it did. And also there are no errors on the error.log

Comment: When it happens but I access as this http: //WEBSITESAMPLE.com/paramA/pathB/xxxx, it loads immediately

Comment: Another thing, there are no errors on the client browser too (ex. css/js failed to load, none).

Comment: it wont give an error obviously, because it loads after some time.. . your problem is the Lags not the error that should come out..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what's going on here because your question lacks a little detail.

But just to make the scenario clear when it comes to Client/ Server side and accessing something on the web with a domain. You have to understand that whatever lags you experience it always points to a certain process that a line of code cannot finish the job in the desired time.

Lags sometimes caused by a script like Javascript(JS) that probably will send request from the server which server can't response in a certain time required by the script.

Also sometimes, browsing to a specified URL without a clear path to a server could cause waiting time.

anyhow, you have to inspect the path you are accessing and the source code and possible process jobs. From there I'm sure you can figure it out.

Otherwise you have to share your setup. Assuming you're the one who setup and build the site.

Comment: I did not setup the server. Also there are no errors on the client side (also on the server side). It also happens rarely not all the time. Seems to be an strange issue.

Comment: then you have to inspect the path or routing of the URL to the server's source file, it should have something like process or queries to db that caused the Lags.

Comment: if you know how to use Firebug or Web Developer Inspector on the browser then I advice you to use it.

Comment: I used Firebug already, no error on the loading of files, the whole website itself doesn't load and it is just blank, until it loads after a certain time.

Comment: Also try to inspect httpd error logs, you might find something there like PHP Fatal errors as there are Fatal errors that are not sent back to browser.

Comment: There are no errors on the server side too (none in error.log), that's why I tried to post it here because it seems to be a strange issue. I'm thinking if the data/API is slow, then there should be a timeout error on the error.log, but there is none. And if I add something on the URL, it loads immediately.

Comment: follow the source code of the lagging URL then inspect which part is going to be loaded first, and which UI on the browser should gets loaded first and inspect UI source code for if it's accessing external url